# Summing values in columns based on other values in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm relatively new to R and am having trouble creating a vector that sums certain values based on other values. I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I don't receive an error, but the output is not what I was looking for. Here is a reproducible example:

```
fakeprice <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, NA, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, NA)
fakeconversion <-c(.2, .15, .07, .25, NA, .4, .36, NA, .67, .42, .01)
fakedata <- data.frame(fakeprice, fakeconversion)
fake.list <- sort(unique(fakedata$fakeprice))
fake.sum <- vector(,5)
```

So, `fakedata` looks like:

```
   fakeprice fakeconversion
1          1           0.20
2          2           0.15
3          2           0.07
4          1           0.25
5         NA             NA
6          5           0.40
7          4           0.36
8          4             NA
9          3           0.67
10         3           0.42
11        NA           0.01
```

I think the problem lies in the NAs, but I'm not quite sure (there are quite a few in the original data set). Here are the for loops with nested if statements. I kept getting an error when the price was 'NA' and so I added the `is.na()`:

```
    for(i in fake.list){
      sum=0
      for(j in fakedata$fakeprice){
        if(is.na(fakedata$fakeprice[j])==TRUE){
          NULL
        } else {
          if(fakedata$fakeprice[j]==fake.list[i]){
            sum <- sum+fakedata$fakeconversion[j]
          }}
      }
      fake.sum[i]=sum
    } 
sumdata <- data.frame(fake.list, fake.sum)
```

I'm looking for an output that adds up `fakeconversion` for each unique price. So, for `fakeprice=1`, `fake.sum=0.45`. The resulting data I am looking for would look like:

```
   fake.list       fake.sum
1          1           0.45
2          2           0.22
3          3           1.09
4          4           0.36
5          5           0.40
```

What I get, however, is:

```
 sumdata
  fake.list fake.sum
1         1     0.90
2         2     0.44
3         3     0.00
4         4     0.00
5         5     0.00
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If R, you wouldn't use loops like that. You'd just use `aggregate(fakeconversion~fakeprice, fakedata, sum)`. That will give you your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggregate(fakedata$fakeconversion, list(price = fakedata$fakeprice), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The above will deal with the `NA` in `fakeprice` `4`.

The `aggregate` function works by subsetting your data `by` something and then running a function, `FUN`.

So:

```
aggregate(x, by, FUN, ...,)
```

`x` is what you wish to run the `FUN` on. `By` can be given a list if you wish to split the data by multiple columns.

Comment: Wow... so much easier. This is perfect!

Comment: Then, i can use `aggregate(fakedata$fakeconversion, list(price = fakedata$fakeprice), mean, na.rm = TRUE)` to get the average for each price. How would I also add in the _n_ for each price as well as the standard error?

Comment: @J.Sweet `aggregate(fakedata$fakeconversion, list(price = fakedata$fakeprice), function(x) c(Sum = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), n = sum(!is.na(x)), SE = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))`. You create a custom function that take the object  and calculates the things you want in vector from: `c(sum, n, std.error)` in this example

Comment: This is SUPER helpful. Thank you so much!